why scala-2.12.15 break can goto outer function?
scala-version: scala-sdk-2.12.15
jdk-version: jdk-8u371
os-version: win10
code:
import scala.util.control.Breaks.{break, breakable}

object TestScala {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    a
  }
  def a {
    breakable {
      for (i <- 1 to 3) {
        println(i)
        b
      }
    }
  }
  def b {
    for (i <- 11 to 15) {
      if (i > 13) break
      println(i)
    }
  }
}

result(No warning at all):
1
11
12
13

why?
I think it should be one of the following results
case 1(compile failed):
error: value break is not a member of object Main.this.b
    if (i > 13) break
                ^

case 2(break is invalid):
1
11
12
13
2
11
12
13
3
11
12
13

So where is the problem? Thank you for your answer

Side note: JDK 8 is old, Scala 2.12 also (unless you're using a framework like Spark), and the syntax def a { should be replaced by def a = {.

The break here is different from break in other languages like Java, Go, etc.
Maybe it helps if you have a look at their definition:
def breakable(op: => Unit): Unit =
    try op catch { case ex: BreakControl if ex eq breakException => }

def break(): Nothing = throw breakException

So your code would actually be:
// note that this does not compile,
// because breakException value and BreakControl class are
// private to that package, this is just for demonstration
def a = {
    try {
      for (i <- 1 to 5) {
        println(i)
        b
      }
    } catch { case ex: BreakControl if ex eq breakException => }
  }
  def b = {
    for (i <- 11 to 15) {
      if (i > 13) throw breakException
      println(i)
    }
  }

When you call method b, an exception is thrown after i passes 13, and since method b does not handle the exception, then the exception handler in method a does, and the way it does it, is just by giving up on the given operation (which is the for loop in method a, or op in the breakable method input).
If you wanna achieve case 2, you need to catch the exception in method b as well:
def a = breakable {
      for (i <- 1 to 5) {
        println(i)
        b
      }
    }
  def b = breakable {
      for (i <- 11 to 15) {
        if (i > 13) break
        println(i)
      }
    }

As a side note, this kind of "imperative" coding is not considered a good practice in Scala, that might be one of the reasons why you don't see break as a language construct, but as a method.
A better way to do so would be something like this:
(1 to 5).foreach { i =>
  println(i)
  (11 to 15).filter(_ <= 13).foreach(println)
}


takeWhile could also be used instead of filter in the idiomatic Scala code. Feels closer to the imperative approach in terms of intent.
